# Able to view new files from a samba share only after refresh

Tags: windows, samba, windows-explorer

I'm currently trying to access a samba share from windows server 2012
When I access the share I'm only able to view 210 files out of 460 files
and the remaining files are only viewable after refresh(F5)
This Issue  also appears to be Intermittent, I'm freaked out with this strange behaviour
and unable to run my scripts on the share they end up with unable to find the files!!
Please help me in resolving this

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a timeout in your scripts? If the problem is intermittent then basically look at it like this.

1) look for a file you know should be there
2) if you can find it continue normal script execution
3) if you can't timeout go back to start of script

Other questions specific to a system or network wide? Network wide else you wouldn't be here?

Does simply listing the directory a second time cause this strange behaviour? Is it some form of caching that needs to be dealt with? Try clearing cache each time?